# What free software can I use to speed up my video?

Tags: video-editor, effects

I have a 90 minute video in which I want to speed up some segments, like a fast forward, preferably with some averaging of video frames to make the motion appear smoother.

What free software can do this, and how do I set up the effect?

Comment: There are many, many questions on this site looking fro free video editing software. I suggest you have a search through them first, and then ask a specific question if you get stuck on something. https://video.stackexchange.com/search?q=free+software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option is Davinci Resolve.

It has a specific feature called Retime controls, where you put a couple of markers and select the speed of that particular segment.

90 Minutes is quite long, you probably want to make some proxy videos at smaller resolution and then render using the original clip.